# Should I make getter of readonly field and why?

Tags: c#, oop

Of course I want that class foobar must/will not modify field aaa except at constructor, and that other classes may see aaa's value.
The class foobar is not sealed now, but perhaps no one wants to make classes inherit from the class foobar.

What is good way?

```
public class foobar
{
    public readonly string aaa;
    public foobar(int param)
    {
        aaa = method(param);
    }
}
```

vs

```
public class foobar
{
    private readonly string aaa;
    public string AAA { get; }
    public foobar(int param)
    {
        aaa = methond(param);
    }
}
```

or others ( I cannot bethink of )

Comment: In general `public` fields are frowned upon in C#, even if the are `readonly`. Exposing the field through a property is probably a good idea, but otherwise this question is totally unclear. "A good way" to do what?

Comment: When we are discussing what is frowned upon in C#, I would also advise to defines classes with the first letter capital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your demands (settable only in constructor and public), use the following.

```
public class foobar
{
    private readonly string aaa;

    public string AAA { get { return aaa; } }

    public foobar(int param)
    {
        aaa = methond(param);
    }
}
```

Then, if you don't want let user to inherit from your class, use `sealed` and you can also make the class `internal`, if it is not somehow accessible from a public API. That way, no one won't even see that this class exists, it will be your implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

I would do following:

```
public sealed class foobar
{
    public string AAA { get; private set; }

    public foobar(int param)
    {
        aaa = method(param);
    }
}
```

But it's just someones opinion.

Comment: This answer doesn't satisfy OPs read only requirement. Private set means this field can be modified after initializing in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

One reason to make a getter is that you will often want other classes that use your class to do so via an interface that your class implements (rather than have a reference of type 'foobar') - and interfaces cannot contain fields.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your use-case, but generally in such situations you can keep those fields as fields until you have *a need* to turn them into properties. The need arises for example when a potential descendant needs to override that field (you then make the field into a virtual property), or when you need to extract an interface from that class, or when you need to serialize that object and the serializer doesn't support fields, etc.

Until then you can keep them as readonly fields, since field access is faster than property access, potentially even more so with readonly fields, since with readonly fields (and also local vars) the compiler/JIT can make better assumptions and optimizations in terms of volatility and caching in registers and such.

Also readonly fields better convey a message to the purpose of the field - a readonly field is clearly stating that the field will never-ever change its value or the object it references during the parent object's lifetime, whereas a property with a private setter doesn't make that guarantee.